# where am I closing the connection in node-mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, node-mysql

Here is my code:

```
var set = {
                FIRST_NAME: professor.value_20,
                SURNAME: professor.value_21
            }
            //logs
            //console.log(set);
            //executes query
            connection.query({
                sql: 'SELECT TEACHERID FROM TEACHER WHERE FIRST_NAME = ? AND SURNAME = ?',
                //'INSERT INTO TEACHER set ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIRST_NAME = ?, SURNAME = ?',
                values: [set.FIRST_NAME,set.SURNAME]
            }, (err, results, fields) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                if(results.length < 0) {
                    connection.query({
                        sql: 'INSERT INTO TEACHER set ?',
                        values: [set]
                    }, (err, results, fields) => {
                        if (err) throw err;

                    });
                }
                else {
                    connection.query({
                        sql: 'UPDATE TEACHER (FIRST_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(?,?)',
                        values: [set.FIRST_NAME, set.SURNAME]

                    }, (err, results, fields) => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        connection.end();
                    });
                }

            });
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
```

The problem seems to occur at the level of the third query, although I did not close the connection earlier. How do I fix this?

Another question: is it better in this case to use a pool instead of a direct connection?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix this?

You have to either remove `connection.end()` or reestablish connection beforehand.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(config); //establish new connection
connection.query({
  sql: 'SELECT TEACHERID FROM TEACHER WHERE FIRST_NAME = ? AND SURNAME = ?',
  //'INSERT INTO TEACHER set ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIRST_NAME = ?, SURNAME = ?',
  values: [set.FIRST_NAME, set.SURNAME]
}, (err, results, fields) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (results.length < 0) {
    connection.query({
      sql: 'INSERT INTO TEACHER set ?',
      values: [set]
    }, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) throw err;

    });
  } else {
    connection.query({
      sql: 'UPDATE TEACHER (FIRST_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(?,?)',
      values: [set.FIRST_NAME, set.SURNAME]

    }, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      connection.end(); //or just remove this line
    });
  }

});
```

I don't recommend the above fixes. The best solution is to use pooling connections.

```
pool.getConnection(function(er,connection){
    if(er){
      throw er;
    }
    connection.query({
      sql: 'SELECT TEACHERID FROM TEACHER WHERE FIRST_NAME = ? AND SURNAME = ?',
      //'INSERT INTO TEACHER set ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIRST_NAME = ?, SURNAME = ?',
      values: [set.FIRST_NAME, set.SURNAME]
    }, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (results.length < 0) {
        connection.query({
          sql: 'INSERT INTO TEACHER set ?',
          values: [set]
        }, (err, results, fields) => {
          if (err) throw err;

        });
      } else {
        connection.query({
          sql: 'UPDATE TEACHER (FIRST_NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(?,?)',
          values: [set.FIRST_NAME, set.SURNAME]

        }, (err, results, fields) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      }

    });
});
```

This approach will remove the overhead of establishing a new connection in each query.